# Connect to a ODBC DSN installed on a server

Tags: delphi, odbc

I am developing an application in Delphi 10.2.3 which connects to a Firebird database installed on a machine running Windows 2016 Server. The application also connects to QuickBooks Online using a third party ODBC driver.  Since this application must be accessed by 12+ users in my company, it will not be cost effective to purchase and install individual ODBC drivers for each user.

The provider of the ODBC driver has a version which can be installed on a server.  Is it possible to configure an ODBC DNS connection on the server which I can access from network clients? If not, can anyone suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Server vs Workstation ODBC driver usually has to do with licensing not connection method. It is always running on the same machine as the software using the connection.

- Web application used by many users running on a server connecting through an ODBC driver = server licensed version of the driver.
- User loading data into Excel on their computer through an ODBC driver
  = client / workstation licensed driver.

Some databases, for example SQL Server, can do a database link through an ODBC driver. This is linking / exposing another database to querying from a host database server. This would allow you to share one server licensed driver. The clients would connect to the host database.

One such driver is DevArt's ODBC Driver for QuickBooks which has a help topic on creating a linked database and testing it in SQL Server Management Studio / SQL Server: [Using in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://www.devart.com/odbc/quickbooks/docs/microsoft_sql_server_manager_s.htm). Might not be applicable if each user needs to use different credentials for the QuickBooks connection.

Comment: Your answer doesn't not address my underlying question.  Putting aside licensing issues, does ODBC technology allow me to create a DNS named QBO-Server on my Win 2016 Server and connect to it directly from my laptop?  Or, does ODBC technology only allow same machine access and to connect from another computer, I will need an additional software component or service to mediate communications between the two?

Comment: It (an ODBC driver) is always running on the same machine as the software using the connection.